# How to render ember template for a nested dynamic route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router, grunt-ember-templates

js`, I have declared some nested routes like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' })
  this.route('orders', function() {
    this.route('details', { path: '/:order_id' });
  });
  this.route('not-found', { path: '/*path' });
});
```

Here the `orders.details` template is not rendering, the but it is going to the correct route file,
Here is the route file:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    const { order_id } = params;
    console.log('params', params);
    return order_id;
  },
  renderTemplate() {
    this.render('orders/details')
  }
});
```

I also declared the template in a nested manner within `orders` folder:
[image]

This does not render the `orders/details` template, it always goes to the `orders` template.
Here is my `orders/details.hbs` template:

```
<h2>Order {{this.model}}</h2>
{{outlet}}
```

Here is how I am navigating to the route:
`{{#link-to 'orders.details' order.id}}{{order.description}}{{/link-to}}`

Comment: How are you navigating to orders.details?

Comment: I updated that in the question @Gaurav

Comment: Is there an {{outlet}} in the orders route template?

Answer (score 0):

As @Gaurav said , see if you didn't forget to use `{{outlet}}` in your Orders template

```
{{!-- Orders.hbs --}}
{{!--  any content for orders--}}
{{outlet}} {{!-- orders.details will load here--}}
```

so if you don't include {{outlet in your orders template , the orders.details won't load }}